# keeping optional(null) and required(not null) data in the same table or separate tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two sets of inputs in a product delivery form -

1. recipient information(**required**) - `(country, state, city, zipcode, street, contact_no)`
2. alternate_recipient_information(**Optional**) - `(country, state, city, zipcode, street, recipient name, contact_no)`

I need an efficient and flexible database schema and here's what I thought might work for me:

`user
id, name, email`

`country
id, country, iso_code`

`state
id, state, country_id`

`city
id, city, state_id`

`address_type
id, type
1   required
2   optional`

`address
id, street(null), city_id(null), state_id(null), country_id(null), type_id`

`recipient
id, user_id, address_id, contact_no`

`alternate_recipient
id, name, address_id, contact_no`

`delivery_info
id, recipient_id, alt_recipient_id(null)`

OR should I just use two separate tables for the required and optional sets of data or am i good to go? are there any better solutions?

Comment: Why do alternate recipients have names but recipients don't?

Comment: alternate recipient can be anyone who doesn't necessarily be a registered user but recipient must be(who has a registered name). @Nick

Comment: Well where are you storing the registered user details? it seems `recipient` ought to point to that...

Comment: Leave the table fields as a default of NULL and don't worry about it. They wont hurt anything. Making 2 tables is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes @Nick. Just Edited .

Comment: I think it looks reasonable. It's possibly more normalised than you actually need, but that's rarely a bad thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In speaking about efficiencies, by splitting the table, you would have to JOIN tables to get the relevant data which is less efficient than having a single table with NULL values that you don't have to worry about. If you are pulling the data later, just use IFNULL and give it a value.

Comment: Based on what I see there, it's a basic user profile table so nothing to be worried about!

Comment: Don't forget to flag an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Making two separate tables will help you to make your structure more normalised but you have basic user profile , so you can continue with the present structure itself.

Comment: the user table gonna grow with some extra column like gender, country, about, profile_pic etc. will it be good in that case?